# Maven plugin loading parent project classses

Tags: java, maven

I am creating a Maven plugin which I have included in my project. So my MOJO has my project reference but is there any way in which my MOJO can have all the dependencies of the project reference as well. The hierarchy is something like the following :

`MyMOJO` (plugin) is included as `<plugin>` in `MyProject`.

`MyProject` has a `<dependency>` of `MyFramework` I created.

Now I want my classloader to have the dependencies of `MyProject` as well as `MyFramework`.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean to say copy the .java file or you want to include as a dependency?

Comment: As a dependency. After looking for four hours I finally got what I was looking for. It is an attribute to `@Mojo` annotation :   `requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.RUNTIME`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

We define mojo class with `@Mojo` annotation with the attribute `requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.RUNTIME` so that mojo resolves all the dependencies including transitives for the project.